# Извлечение скрипта из AssetBundle на iOS

Tags: ios, unity3d

Весь контент приложения, включая сцены и скрипты, должен подгружаться из бандла, скачиваемого с сервера. На андроиде особых проблем с этим нет, там можно использовать `System.Reflection`, но в документации Unity сказано, что рефлексия недоступна для устройств c AOT-компиляцией, т.е. для iOS. Как в таком случае я могу подвязать скрипт к объекту на сцене с учетом, что в ближайшем обновлении скрипт может поменяться и его надо будет заменить?

Comment: Повесить на ГО скрипт-интерфейс, а логику вынести в библиотеку, и её обновлять?

Comment: Наверное, так сделать можно, но вот методы Start и Update... Если предположить, что количество сцен может меняться, и на каждой сцене могут быть абсолютно разные ГО, то для определения какие именно ГО должны инициализироваться должна быть какая-то проверка в старте и в апдейте. Т.е. фактически метод старт определенной сцены должен вызывать метод старт какого-то класса из библиотеки. Получается надо заранее добавлять в библиотеку скрипты без функционала для потенциальных сцен, которые по мере надобности наполнять логикой и подгружать обновлением, если я все правильно понял.

Comment: У вас есть возможность проверить рефлексию? Потому что [вот тут](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/207670/using-reflection-with-ios.html) пишут, что вроде как работает, но с оговорками. Правда, это 2012 год

Comment: Потестить, к сожалению, возможности пока нету, но [вот тут](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/26191/systemreflection-on-ios-in-unity-3.html) пишут, что динамическая генерация кода все же не работает. Работает в целом Reflection API со списками методов и получением типа данных